# Get customer ID using Mage::getModel('customer/customer')

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I not able to get the customersID am I calling it correctly with `Mage::getModel`

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    ->setWebsiteId(2)
    ->load($this->getRequest()->getParam('customer'));

$customer_id = $customer->getId();
$sku = 'BOX3151';

$sql = "SELECT sfoi.item_id FROM sales_flat_order_item sfoi INNER JOIN sales_flat_order sfo
ON sfo.entity_id = sfoi.order_id WHERE sfo.customer_id = '$customer_id' AND sfoi.sku = '$sku'";
$read_db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$result = $read_db->fetchAll($sql);
$total_rows = count($result);
    if($total_rows >= 1):
        echo ' Found ';
    else:
        echo ' Empty ';
    endif;
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check for available data in
$this->getRequest()->getParam('customer')

if you have **$customerId** there you can use the load() method.

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    ->setWebsiteId(2)
    ->load($customerId)
```

also you can get customer object by **$email**.

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    ->setWebsiteId(2)
    ->loadByEmail($email);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$email = "customer@gmail.com";
$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId())->loadByEmail($email);
//use
echo $customer->getId();
echo $customer->getEmail(); 
echo $customer->getFirstname(); 
?>
```